# Changing content of a div with JS breaks my bootstrap row alignment on mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see [HERE](http://northgoal.com.ar/expedientes/alta.php?tipo=mov) my website has a `Div`(id="basic-addon13") whose content changes when a value on the table (id="table") is clicked.

This works perfectly on PC, and should work fine in mobiles as I am using Bootstrap rows to arrage content.

But what actually happens on mobiles is that, the span tag won't show in two lines and is simply shown parcially. You can check that out [HERE](http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://northgoal.com.ar/expedientes/alta.php?tipo=mov).

How can I avoid this from happening? shouldn't bootstrap rows arrange content in two lines and not simply "break"?

CODE: [view-source:http://northgoal.com.ar/expedientes/alta.php?tipo=mov](http://view-source:http://northgoal.com.ar/expedientes/alta.php?tipo=mov)

Comment: Which `div` and `table` you are asking about? Not clear. Can u elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Jyothi, I have improved my question. I am refering to Div(id="basic-addon13") and  table (id="table").

Comment: Remove `white-space: nowrap;` from class `.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn`

Comment: Thanks Pankit! make it a comment so i can choose it as my answer. I would love to fully understand bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet there is a property `white-space: nowrap` is applied to the class `.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn`

`white-space: nowrap` property will not wrap your text depending on the element width.

[**Refer:** Using Boostrap class `.input-group-btn` and `.input-group-addon`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic)